# JPA Entity Persisting another entity

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, entity

I have a "sale" entity, before the entity is persisted, I'd like to create an "Income" entity. I could do this in a session bean but I'd like it better if it was encapsulated inside the Sale entity. So I could do:

```
em.persist(sale);
```

And it'd automatically create an Income entity and persist it as well.

I don't want Sale to have an association with Income because I could associate them and do a cascade persist.

It's like if the sale entity would create an instance of the Income entity and then call the persist method on the EntityManager, since this is neither posible nor a good idea I am beginning to think that it should be performed by the EJB. Opinions?

Comment: Is there a reason why you prefer not to persist the Income entity directly from your EJB? I don't see what this would offer you other than having a design that would possibly be more difficult for other people working with/maintaining your code to follow.

Comment: @Christina, I am not sure, I thought that if it was done by the Sale entity it would hide that complexity from the upper layers so that I don't have to remember to create both entities everytime I create a Sale. I don't have much experience on this, is that not a good idea?

Comment: Personnaly I wouldn't do it unless I had a really good reason since normally people don't expect entities to do things out of the ordinary like that. If you need to create both entities at many places in your code you could always have a private method in your EJB (or even in a helper class if it needs to be called from more than one EJBs) that does that. This has the advantage that people reading your code see the method being called and can see what it does instead of relying on a PrePersist annotation or anything similar that most people won't look for if they don't know it's there.

Comment: Looks like there's a one-to-one relation between Sale and Income. Why not model them as such and then follow Padmarag's advice?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the @PrePersist annotation?

[JPA prepersist](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/EntityListenersPrePersist.htm)

Comment: yes but this won't persist the entity unless i associate both instances and do a cascade persist